# Запуск анимации перемещения UIView во время действия другой такой же без её завершения?

Tags: objective-c

Есть анимация:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
    self.imageView.center = point;
}];
```

Нужно запустить такую же, только с новым значением point, чтобы imageView двигался по прямой. Если ничего не указывать, то картинка выполняет движение по дуге вначале в сторону point из первой анимации, а потом начинает движение к точке point второй анимации. Мне нужно убрать эту дугу. Если удалять первую анимацию, то вьюха прыгает в конечную точку и от туда начинает движение. Опция UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState , к сожалению, не помогает =(

Comment: попробовал у себя - все работает. покажите код

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой вариант: когда надо запускать вторую анимацию, смотрите положение объекта через layer, убирайте анимацию, ставьте руками объект в текущую позицию и запускайте вторую анимацию.

Вот так узнать текущую позицию анимируемого объекта

```
CGRect current = [[self.aView.layer presentationLayer] frame];
```

Вот такой текстик работает отлично

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    self.aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.aView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
        self.aView.center = CGPointMake(325, 50);
    }];
    [self performSelector:@selector(shift) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
}

- (void)shift {

    CGRect current = [[self.aView.layer presentationLayer] frame];
    [self.aView.layer removeAllAnimations];
    self.aView.frame = current;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        self.aView.center = CGPointMake(150, 300);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        //Первая анимация
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            //Вторая анимация
        }];
    }];
```

Comment: в вопросе спрашивается, как прервать текущую анимацию  запустить новую, а вы указываете как запустить новую после окончания текущей